# ORA-12704 CHARACTER SET MISMATCH ( ORACLE PL/SQL )

Tags: oracle, plsql

i'm getting the ora-12704 error for the pl/sql query below - can anyone help point me in the right direction for a solution please?

```
SELECT "STAT"."ORD"."SAMPLEID",

MAX(CASE WHEN "STAT"."ORDANAEL"."MC"='QAERS' THEN "STAT"."ORDANAEL"."RES_TXT" ELSE 

'' END)  AS ERSID,

"STAT"."ORDMCSTP_V"."SEQNB", "STAT"."ORD"."ORDPATNAME", 

"STAT"."ORD"."ORDPATBIRTHDT", "STAT"."ORD"."CORORDNB", "STAT"."ORD"."PROJNB",

Max(CASE WHEN "STAT"."ORDANAEL"."MC"='AMMOL' THEN 'AMMOL' 

WHEN "STAT"."ORDANAEL"."MC"='AMMOLR' THEN 'AMMOLR' ELSE '' END) AS TEST, 


Max(CASE WHEN "STAT"."ORDANAEL"."MC"='AMMOL' THEN "STAT"."ORDRESMCEL"."MC_RES"

WHEN "STAT"."ORDANAEL"."MC"='AMMOLR' THEN "STAT"."ORDRESMCEL"."MC_RES" ELSE '' 

END) AS MC_RES, 



Max( CASE WHEN "STAT"."ORDMCSTP_V"."STEPMC"='AMIMI' THEN "STAT"."ORDMCSTPEL"."RES" 

ELSE '' END) AS IMI, 

Max( CASE WHEN "STAT"."ORDMCSTP_V"."STEPMC"='AMIMP' THEN "STAT"."ORDMCSTPEL"."RES" 

ELSE '' END)  AS IMP, 

Max( CASE WHEN "STAT"."ORDMCSTP_V"."STEPMC"='AMNDM' THEN "STAT"."ORDMCSTPEL"."RES" 

ELSE '' END)  AS NDM, 

Max( CASE WHEN "STAT"."ORDMCSTP_V"."STEPMC"='AMOX48' THEN 

"STAT"."ORDMCSTPEL"."RES" ELSE '' END)  AS OXA48, 

Max( CASE WHEN "STAT"."ORDMCSTP_V"."STEPMC"='AMSPM' THEN "STAT"."ORDMCSTPEL"."RES" 

ELSE '' END)  AS SPM, 

Max( CASE WHEN "STAT"."ORDMCSTP_V"."STEPMC"='AMVIM' THEN "STAT"."ORDMCSTPEL"."RES" 

ELSE '' END)  AS VIM, 

Max( CASE WHEN "STAT"."ORDMCSTP_V"."STEPMC"='AMDIM' THEN "STAT"."ORDMCSTPEL"."RES" 

ELSE '' END)  AS DIM, 

Max( CASE WHEN "STAT"."ORDMCSTP_V"."STEPMC"='AMKPC' THEN "STAT"."ORDMCSTPEL"."RES" 

ELSE '' END)  AS KPC, 

Max( CASE WHEN "STAT"."ORDMCSTP_V"."STEPMC"='AMGES' THEN"STAT"."ORDMCSTPEL"."RES" 

ELSE '' END)  AS GES, 

Max( CASE WHEN "STAT"."ORDMCSTP_V"."STEPMC"='AMSME' THEN "STAT"."ORDMCSTPEL"."RES" 

ELSE '' END)  AS SME, 

Max( CASE WHEN "STAT"."ORDMCSTP_V"."STEPMC"='AMFRI1' THEN 

"STAT"."ORDMCSTPEL"."RES" ELSE '' END)  AS FRI1, 

Max( CASE WHEN "STAT"."ORDMCSTP_V"."STEPMC"='AMSIM' THEN "STAT"."ORDMCSTPEL"."RES" 

ELSE '' END)  AS SIM, 

Max( CASE WHEN "STAT"."ORDMCSTP_V"."STEPMC"='AMGIM' THEN "STAT"."ORDMCSTPEL"."RES" 

ELSE '' END)  AS GIM,



Max( CASE WHEN "STAT"."ORDANAEL"."MC"='AMMOL' THEN "STAT"."ORDANAEL"."VALMED" ELSE 

'' END)  AS VALMED_AMMOL, 

Max( CASE WHEN "STAT"."ORDANAEL"."MC"='AMMOL' AND 

"STAT"."ORDANAEL_D"."DFIELD"='RR' THEN "STAT"."ORDANAEL_D"."DVALUE" ELSE '' END)  

AS RPT_DT_AMMOL, 

"STAT"."ORDANAEL"."RES_ST" 



FROM (("STAT"."ORDMCSTPEL" INNER JOIN ("STAT"."ORDMCSTP_V" INNER JOIN 

("STAT"."ORD" INNER JOIN "STAT"."ORDANAEL" ON ("STAT"."ORD"."LID" = 

"STAT"."ORDANAEL"."LID") AND ("STAT"."ORD"."LPERIOD" = 

"STAT"."ORDANAEL"."LPERIOD") AND ("STAT"."ORD"."ORDNB" = 

"STAT"."ORDANAEL"."ORDNB")) ON ("STAT"."ORDMCSTP_V"."LID" = "STAT"."ORD"."LID") 

AND ("STAT"."ORDMCSTP_V"."LPERIOD" = "STAT"."ORD"."LPERIOD") AND 

("STAT"."ORDMCSTP_V"."ORDNB" = "STAT"."ORD"."ORDNB")) ON ("STAT"."ORDMCSTPEL"."BC" 

= "STAT"."ORDMCSTP_V"."BC") AND ("STAT"."ORDMCSTPEL"."CURRENT_STEPNB" = 

"STAT"."ORDMCSTP_V"."CURRENT_STEPNB")) INNER JOIN "STAT"."ORDANAEL_D" ON 

("STAT"."ORDANAEL"."NBINT" = "STAT"."ORDANAEL_D"."DNBINT") AND 

("STAT"."ORDANAEL"."SPSEQ" = "STAT"."ORDANAEL_D"."DSPSEQ") AND 

("STAT"."ORDANAEL"."ORDNB" = "STAT"."ORDANAEL_D"."DORDNB") AND 

("STAT"."ORDANAEL"."LPERIOD" = "STAT"."ORDANAEL_D"."DLPERIOD") AND 

("STAT"."ORDANAEL"."LID" = "STAT"."ORDANAEL_D"."DLID")) INNER JOIN 

"STAT"."ORDRESMCEL" ON ("STAT"."ORDMCSTP_V"."SEQNB" = "STAT"."ORDRESMCEL"."SEQNB") 

AND ("STAT"."ORDANAEL"."ORDNB" = "STAT"."ORDRESMCEL"."ORDNB") AND 

("STAT"."ORDANAEL"."LPERIOD" = "STAT"."ORDRESMCEL"."LPERIOD") AND 

("STAT"."ORDANAEL"."LID" = "STAT"."ORDRESMCEL"."LID")





WHERE (("STAT"."ORD"."LID")='H1')

AND (("STAT"."ORD"."LPERIOD")>'5200') 

AND (("STAT"."ORD"."PROJNB")='ACPOERS')



GROUP BY "STAT"."ORD"."SAMPLEID", "STAT"."ORDMCSTP_V"."SEQNB", 

"STAT"."ORD"."ORDPATNAME", "STAT"."ORD"."ORDPATBIRTHDT", "STAT"."ORD"."CORORDNB", 

"STAT"."ORD"."PROJNB", "STAT"."ORDANAEL"."RES_ST"
HAVING ((("STAT"."ORDMCSTP_V"."SEQNB") Is Not Null) AND (("STAT"."ORD"."PROJNB")

='ACPOERS') AND (("STAT"."ORDANAEL"."RES_ST")>'4'))
```

Comment: Why do you enclose all identifier by double-quotes? It is not required t Oracle. Do you have any `NVARCHAR2` and `VARCHAR2` mixed  in the tables?

Comment: You may get proper answer if you would format your SQL statement little better.

Comment: I tried this query before a change and it only worked with the double quotes.  i cannot tell if there are nvarchar2 and varchar2 in the tables as i don't have sight of the tables.  the query ran successfuly before and the tables were re-built on an upgrade.  so i don't know how to modify the query to make it work again

Comment: some forums seem to indicate that i put a "N" after any "THEN" in the statement? to correct for the nvarchar2?

Comment: I suspect it "doesn't work" without the double quotes because of this: `THEN"STAT"."ORDMCSTPEL"."RES" `, i.e. a missing space after `THEN`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that its because literals in the query and using of some NVARCHAR2 columns
in the compares. and also there is a bug in this part

```
Max( CASE WHEN STAT.ORDMCSTP_V.STEPMC=n'AMGES' THENSTAT.ORDMCSTPEL.RES ELSE n'' END)  AS GES,
```

THENSTAT need a space

pleas check this type of query and change some literals same as 'ABC' to n'ABC' according to witch column is NVARCHAR2.

if all of the columns are NVARCHAR2 then the query must be something like this:

```
 SELECT STAT.ORD.SAMPLEID,
   MAX(CASE
         WHEN STAT.ORDANAEL.MC = n'QAERS' THEN
          STAT.ORDANAEL.RES_TXT
         ELSE
          n''
       END) AS ERSID,
   STAT.ORDMCSTP_V.SEQNB,
   STAT.ORD.ORDPATNAME,
   STAT.ORD.ORDPATBIRTHDT,
   STAT.ORD.CORORDNB,
   STAT.ORD.PROJNB,
   Max(CASE
         WHEN STAT.ORDANAEL.MC = n'AMMOL' THEN
          n'AMMOL'
         WHEN STAT.ORDANAEL.MC = n'AMMOLR' THEN
          n'AMMOLR'
         ELSE
          n''
       END) AS TEST,
   Max(CASE
         WHEN STAT.ORDANAEL.MC = n'AMMOL' THEN
          STAT.ORDRESMCEL.MC_RES
         WHEN STAT.ORDANAEL.MC = n'AMMOLR' THEN
          STAT.ORDRESMCEL.MC_RES
         ELSE
          n''
       END) AS MC_RES,
   Max(CASE
         WHEN STAT.ORDMCSTP_V.STEPMC = n'AMIMI' THEN
          STAT.ORDMCSTPEL.RES
         ELSE
          n''
       END) AS IMI,
   Max(CASE
         WHEN STAT.ORDMCSTP_V.STEPMC = n'AMIMP' THEN
          STAT.ORDMCSTPEL.RES
         ELSE
          n''
       END) AS IMP,
   Max(CASE
         WHEN STAT.ORDMCSTP_V.STEPMC = n'AMNDM' THEN
          STAT.ORDMCSTPEL.RES
         ELSE
          n''
       END) AS NDM,
   Max(CASE
         WHEN STAT.ORDMCSTP_V.STEPMC = n'AMOX48' THEN
          STAT.ORDMCSTPEL.RES
         ELSE
          n''
       END) AS OXA48,
   Max(CASE
         WHEN STAT.ORDMCSTP_V.STEPMC = n'AMSPM' THEN
          STAT.ORDMCSTPEL.RES
         ELSE
          n''
       END) AS SPM,
   Max(CASE
         WHEN STAT.ORDMCSTP_V.STEPMC = n'AMVIM' THEN
          STAT.ORDMCSTPEL.RES
         ELSE
          n''
       END) AS VIM,
   Max(CASE
         WHEN STAT.ORDMCSTP_V.STEPMC = n'AMDIM' THEN
          STAT.ORDMCSTPEL.RES
         ELSE
          n''
       END) AS DIM,
   Max(CASE
         WHEN STAT.ORDMCSTP_V.STEPMC = n'AMKPC' THEN
          STAT.ORDMCSTPEL.RES
         ELSE
          n''
       END) AS KPC,
   Max(CASE
         WHEN STAT.ORDMCSTP_V.STEPMC = n'AMGES' THEN
          STAT.ORDMCSTPEL.RES
         ELSE
          n''
       END) AS GES,
   Max(CASE
         WHEN STAT.ORDMCSTP_V.STEPMC = n'AMSME' THEN
          STAT.ORDMCSTPEL.RES
         ELSE
          n''
       END) AS SME,
   Max(CASE
         WHEN STAT.ORDMCSTP_V.STEPMC = n'AMFRI1' THEN
          STAT.ORDMCSTPEL.RES
         ELSE
          n''
       END) AS FRI1,
   Max(CASE
         WHEN STAT.ORDMCSTP_V.STEPMC = n'AMSIM' THEN
          STAT.ORDMCSTPEL.RES
         ELSE
          n''
       END) AS SIM,
   Max(CASE
         WHEN STAT.ORDMCSTP_V.STEPMC = n'AMGIM' THEN
          STAT.ORDMCSTPEL.RES
         ELSE
          n''
       END) AS GIM,
   Max(CASE
         WHEN STAT.ORDANAEL.MC = n'AMMOL' THEN
          STAT.ORDANAEL.VALMED
         ELSE
          n''
       END) AS VALMED_AMMOL,
   Max(CASE
         WHEN STAT.ORDANAEL.MC = n'AMMOL' AND STAT.ORDANAEL_D.DFIELD = n'RR' THEN
          STAT.ORDANAEL_D.DVALUE
         ELSE
          n''
       END) RPT_DT_AMMOL,
   STAT.ORDANAEL.RES_ST
FROM STAT.ORDMCSTPEL,
   STAT.ORDMCSTP_V,
   STAT.ORD,
   STAT.ORDANAEL,
   STAT.ORDANAEL_D,
   STAT.ORDRESMCEL
WHERE (STAT.ORD.LID = STAT.ORDANAEL.LID)
  AND (STAT.ORD.LPERIOD = STAT.ORDANAEL.LPERIOD)
  AND (STAT.ORD.ORDNB = STAT.ORDANAEL.ORDNB)
  AND (STAT.ORDMCSTP_V.LID = STAT.ORD.LID)
  AND (STAT.ORDMCSTP_V.LPERIOD = STAT.ORD.LPERIOD)
  AND (STAT.ORDMCSTP_V.ORDNB = STAT.ORD.ORDNB)
  AND (STAT.ORDMCSTPEL.BC = STAT.ORDMCSTP_V.BC)
  AND (STAT.ORDMCSTPEL.CURRENT_STEPNB = STAT.ORDMCSTP_V.CURRENT_STEPNB)
  AND (STAT.ORDANAEL.NBINT = STAT.ORDANAEL_D.DNBINT)
  AND (STAT.ORDANAEL.SPSEQ = STAT.ORDANAEL_D.DSPSEQ)
  AND (STAT.ORDANAEL.ORDNB = STAT.ORDANAEL_D.DORDNB)
  AND (STAT.ORDANAEL.LPERIOD = STAT.ORDANAEL_D.DLPERIOD)
  AND (STAT.ORDANAEL.LID = STAT.ORDANAEL_D.DLID)
  AND (STAT.ORDMCSTP_V.SEQNB = STAT.ORDRESMCEL.SEQNB)
  AND (STAT.ORDANAEL.ORDNB = STAT.ORDRESMCEL.ORDNB)
  AND (STAT.ORDANAEL.LPERIOD = STAT.ORDRESMCEL.LPERIOD)
  AND (STAT.ORDANAEL.LID = STAT.ORDRESMCEL.LID)
  AND ((STAT.ORD.LID) = n'H1')
  AND ((STAT.ORD.LPERIOD) > '5200')
  AND ((STAT.ORD.PROJNB) = n'ACPOERS')
GROUP BY STAT.ORD.SAMPLEID,
      STAT.ORDMCSTP_V.SEQNB,
      STAT.ORD.ORDPATNAME,
      STAT.ORD.ORDPATBIRTHDT,
      STAT.ORD.CORORDNB,
      STAT.ORD.PROJNB,
      STAT.ORDANAEL.RES_ST
HAVING(((STAT.ORDMCSTP_V.SEQNB) Is Not Null) AND ((STAT.ORD.PROJNB) = n'ACPOERS') AND ((STAT.ORDANAEL.RES_ST) > '4'))
```